# webpack extract-text-plugin output multiple css files

Tags: javascript, webpack, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm trying to get my webpack build to export 2 css files, one for all the lib files, and one for my files. I am requiring both files separately into my main.js. Atm it is merging all css requires into 1 file.

Only way I have been able to generate files is by splitting the entry:

```
entry: {
    lib:'./style/lib.scss',
    app: [
      './src/index.js',
      './style/style.scss',
    ],
  },
```

But the lib.scss generated is a duplicate of style, and this method also creates a redudant lib.js. Is there any way to create 2 separate css files, or to set any css that is required needs to be exported individually and not merged into single file?

Answer (score 3):

You split your CSS lib from style by using different Pluggin instances:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Create multiple instances
const extractStyle = new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css');
const extractLib = new ExtractTextPlugin('lib.css');
```

And different folders for the scss as well:

```
           {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                include: resolve(__dirname, './../app/stylesheets'),
                loader: extractLib.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                include: resolve(__dirname, './../app/src'),
                use: extractStyle.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
```

You can see the full example here: https://github.com/jquintozamora/webpack-multiple-css-output/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.js

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work for me, i get this error

Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

| @import BEM.scss

Comment: Make sure you have all your scss files imported from lib under app/stylesheets folder

Comment: Just a note that extract-text-webpack-plugin has been deprecated and it is recommended to switch to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin